# Styling rubberbands using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, style, qgsrubberband

I would like to add an on-map drawing function in my stand alone app, so I used `QgsRubberBand` to make it. I made a tool that emits points and then draw the `QgsRubberBand`. The problem is I don't find any solution to style it (applying a qml file would be perfect). 
Here is the code I use to draw my QgsRubberBand:

```
    def update_largage_eau_canadaire(self, model):
        points = model.largage_eau_canadaire
        #points is an array of QgsPoint
        if len(points) > - 1:
            if self.largage_c_rubber_ is None:
                self.largage_c_rubber_ = QgsRubberBand(self.canvas_, False)

            self.largage_c_rubber_.setToGeometry(QgsGeometry. fromPolyline(points), None)
            self.largage_c_rubber_.setColor(QColor(255, 0, 0, 255))
            self.largage_c_rubber_.setWidth(2)
```

Here is the result:

[image: Screenshot of my drawn rubberband]

And I would like do draw a styled rubberband that would look like this:
[image: Example of the result I expect]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a style like this is impossible for `QgsRubberBands`. You may set the line style with `QgsRubberBand.setLineStyle(p)` where `p` is a value from `Qt.PenStyle` enumerator, which provides a variety of basic line patterns, but unfortunately no ones as complex as yours.

Reference:

https://qgis.org/api/classQgsRubberBand.html#a6f7cdabfcf69b65dfc6c164ce2d01fab)`

https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qt.html#PenStyle-enum

Comment: This is correct - it's not possible to use custom line styles with the rubber band. You may be better off creating a temporary memory layer with a feature matching your rubber band geometry, and then you can style it anyway you want.

Comment: Do you have any idea of the way I could match my rubber band to a layer?

Comment: not sure, but check out wether Settings | Snapping Options... does affect your `QgsMapToolEmitPoint`

Comment: but I totally agree with @ndawson that memory layers are a far better approach for you than rubber bands. No coding needed, can be made persistent, better styling options, ...